# uint16_t subtraction GCC compilation error

Tags: c, gcc, integer-promotion, uint16

I have the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t o = 100;
    uint32_t i1 = 30;
    uint32_t i2 = 20;

    o = (uint16_t) (o - (i1 - i2)); /*Case A*/
    o -= (uint16_t) (i1 - i2);      /*Case B*/
    (void)o;
    return 0;
}
```

**Case A** compiles with no errors.
**Case B** causes the following error
`[error: conversion to ‘uint16_t’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]]`

The warning options I'm using are:
`-Werror -Werror=strict-prototypes -pedantic-errors -Wconversion -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function`

I'm using GCC 4.9.2 on Ubuntu 15.04 64-bits.

Why do I get this error in **Case B** but not in **Case A**?

PS:
I ran the same example with clang compiler and both cases are compiled fine.

Comment: Why would you do that in first place?

Comment: Don't use those options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer Promotion is a strange thing. Basically, all integer values, of any smaller size, are promoted to `int` so they can be operated on efficiently, and then converted back to the smaller size when stored. This is mandated by the C standard.

So, Case A really looks like this:

```
o = (uint16_t) ((int)o - ((uint32_t)i1 - (uint32_t)i2));
```

(Note that `uint32_t` does not fit in `int`, so needs no promotion.)

And, Case B really looks like this:

```
o = (int)o - (int)(uint16_t) ((uint32_t)i1 - (uint32_t)i2);
```

The main difference is that Case A has an explicit cast, whereas Case B has an implicit conversion.

From the GCC manual:

> -Wconversion
>
> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. ....

So, only Case B gets a warning.

Comment: Well, yes, 16-bit int would give difference results.

Answer (score 1):

Your case B is equivalent to:

```
o = o - (uint16_t) (i1 - i2);      /*Case B*/
```

The result is an `int` which may not fit in `uint16_t`, so, per your extreme warning options, it produces a warning (and thus an error since you're treating warnings as errors).

Comment: The result *does* fit in uint16_t in this code, so the compiler is being lazy.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, feel free to fix it.

Comment: @ams no doubt I'd then have to wage war with a bunch of people who want to see this warning even when it is bogus

Comment: I imagine it's just that the warning is emitted before constant propagation occurs. Fixing it probably requires more code than is worthwhile.

Comment: The same error is generated with all the following optimization options `[O0, O1, O2, O3, Os]`